# Creating a list of tuples by cross referencing three dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, graph, tuples

I've been trying to create a Kevin Bacon game, and I think I am nearly done. However I am having a problem building the graph from certain files. There are three files, an actor file which has the actor id and then the actor name, a movie file which has the movie id and movie name, and an movie-actor file which has the movie id and the actor id.

These are the test files I created:

Note: When opening these files, you may need to specify the encoding so Python doesn't crash: e.g. open(r"actors.txt", "r", encoding="latin-1")

[actorsTest](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XQj8jxRaqPGy1APLnniyPqXzLF95fIjU)

[moviesTest](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1glVGx69-k4Ke4GIh8PAy7LY0wqOz7kbe)

[movies-actorsTest](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1brKy0t0wzTVD_TKKoQsM5ptBScTuWnfX)

I want to use these files to create a graph where the vertices are the actor names.

Like So:

vertices:
  "Kevin Bacon", "actor1", "actor2", "actor3", "actor4", "actor5", "actor6"]

And the edges are a tuple consisting of the first actor, second actor, and movie title.

Like so:

edges:

("Kevin Bacon", "actor1", "movie1")

("Kevin Bacon", "actor2", "movie1")

("actor1", "actor2", "movie1")

("actor1", "actor3", "movie2")

("actor3", "actor2", "movie3")

("actor3", "actor4", "movie4")

("actor5", "actor6", "movie5")

This is my code so far:

```
with open('actorsTest.txt') as file:
    actors = [l.strip().split('|') for l in file]
#print(actors)  

with open('moviesTest.txt') as file:
    movies = [l.strip().split('|') for l in file]
#print(movies)

with open('movie-actorsTest.txt') as file:
    movie_actors = [l.strip().split('|') for l in file]
#print(movie_actors)

ma_dict = {}
for i in range(len(movie_actors)):
    if movie_actors[i][0] not in ma_dict.keys():
        ma_dict[movie_actors[i][0]] = []

for i in range(len(movie_actors)):
    ma_dict[movie_actors[i][0]].append(movie_actors[i][1])
print(ma_dict)

a_dict = {d[0]: d[1:] for d in actors}
print(a_dict)

m_dict = {d[0]: d[1:] for d in movies}
print(m_dict)



## These code chunks below this statement do not work, they are my attempt 
## at trying to combine the dictionaries to get the edges to be in the 
## correct format.
edges = []

for k, v in ma_dict:
    for i in range(len(v)-1):
        edges.append((a_dict[v[i]], a_dict[v[i+1]], m_dict[k]))
print(edges)
```

I was able to open the files, parse them line by line, and create three different dictionaries. The actors dictionary has the actor id as the key and the actor name as the value. The movies dictionary has the movie id as the key and the movie name as the value. The movie_actors dictionary has the movie id as the key and a list of actor ids as the value.

Here are the actual actor, movie, and movie-actors files if you wish to see those. These are the files I will actually be running the code on and creating the graph to illustrate the Kevin Bacon game with. The others were just some test files I made.

[actors](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18VDmEMVg1EH-QZdNj-tVtuW70ndZLepf)

[movies](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16klGGnEkNgeasX_2RoeTH0ybfAlqmmur)

[movies-actors](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_wE5pjoCXyVChW4R-aCNi0rL9QmZcx6T)

I've  been puzzling over how to combine these three together to make the edges and vertices but have been unsuccessful so far. I have a feeling its not that hard and there is something I'm just not seeing.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thank you for your time, and please ask me if you need any more information, code snippets, or have any questions.

Comment: I suggest look at [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html) package.

Comment: I have used that package, in fact in the same program I am doing this. However, I am mainly using it for graph visualization, is there some additional functionality which combines dictionaries?